protocolKit.executeTransaction(safeTransaction)
Hello I am trying to use:
safe-core-sdk/playground/api-kit
/propose-transaction.ts
And when I try to execute the execute-transaction.ts file, it throws me the following:
Error: exceeded maximum retry limit (request={  }, response={  }, error=null, info={ "requestUrl": "https://sepolia.gateway.tenderly.co", "responseBody": "{"id":33,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32005,"message":"rate limit exceeded"}}", "responseStatus": "599 CLIENT ESCALATED SERVER ERROR (429 Too Many Requests; exceeded maximum retry limit)" }, code=SERVER_ERROR, version=6.13.2)
at makeError (C:\Users\anselmo.sanchez\smartContracts\api-kit\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:129:21)
at assert (C:\Users\anselmo.sanchez\smartContracts\api-kit\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:149:15)
at FetchResponse.assertOk (C:\Users\anselmo.sanchez\smartContracts\api-kit\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\fetch.js:839:32)
at JsonRpcProvider._send (C:\Users\anselmo.sanchez\smartContracts\api-kit\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:898:18)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async C:\Users\anselmo.sanchez\smartContracts\api-kit\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:281:40 {
code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
request: FetchRequest {},
response: FetchResponse {},
error: undefined,
info: {
requestUrl: 'https://sepolia.gateway.tenderly.co',
responseBody: '{"id":33,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32005,"message":"rate limit exceeded"}}',
responseStatus: '599 CLIENT ESCALATED SERVER ERROR (429 Too Many Requests; exceeded maximum retry limit)'
},
shortMessage: 'exceeded maximum retry limit'
}

You have exceeded tenderly API usage limits; you can either wait a little before trying again or use your own RPC URL, either on Tenderly or other services like Infura.
You can set the RPC URL in the config object of the file.
Hope that helps; Best, Louis
